# I am trying to get NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException but i am not getting it any clue why i am not getting

Tags: spring

I am trying to get NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException but i am not getting it any clue why i am not getting

```
package com.example.demo;

public interface IDateGen {

}

package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class DateGen implements IDateGen {

}


package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class DateGen2 implements IDateGen  {

}
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class DateGenUtil {

    @Autowired
    private IDateGen dateGen;

    public IDateGen getDateGen() {
        return dateGen;
    }

    public void setDateGen(IDateGen dateGen) {
        this.dateGen = dateGen;
    }
    
}

package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo3Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext appContext =   SpringApplication.run(Demo3Application.class, args);
        DateGenUtil util =  appContext.getBean(DateGenUtil.class);
        
        System.out.println(util.getDateGen());
    }

}
```

When i run the main method i getting

com.example.demo.DateGen@6075b2d3

Can anyone tell why i am not getting NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The dependency injection first checks for autoWiring by type and then autowire by name, wen it looks for dateGen dependency in class DateGenUtil it checks by type then it is getting two Objects, then again it tries to do autoWiringByName it gets the one object

if we rename the variable like in the below code it gives the exception, hope anyone can confirm this

```
@Component
public class DateGenUtil {

    @Autowired
    //private IDateGen dateGen;
    private IDateGen date;
    
}
```